# Delete pictures within relative selection in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am just doing something fun in Excel and I have no experience with VBA, and this is not a serious issue, but it would be nice to know.

I have made a picture of a penguin capable to move to left, right, up, and down with macros (because that seemed to be the simplest way). That alone is no fun, so I added pictures of fish, and this penguin has to be able to "eat" them. I want to remove/delete pictures to 2 cells in front of the penguin, but since the images just float above the sheet, I cannot just record a macro, select cells and press "delete". Also, the other problem is, I only know how to select one (or more) pictures with an array not within a specified range.

Is there a way I can do this? All I find is about deleting *all* images in the worksheet, or just deleting all images in certain cells (not relative cells). It has to be a macro (shortcut: Ctrl-Shift-E), and it has to be within two cells from the penguin's right.

[Picture of penguin mini game thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfToG.png)

Comment: The picture looks awesome. Would it be possible to see the excel macro? :)

Comment: Sure thang. Made a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/xhZthsJc

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter I forgot to tag you. :v

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to do the following:

- format the size of the cells so, that each fish is in exactly one cell;
- write randomly the fishes per cell, changing their names with some coordinates at the end (e.g. picr3c19 is the fish on row3, column19);
- whenever the penguin is in such a cell, simply delete the picture with On Error Resume Next. If there is no picture in the cell, then it would be still ok;
- share the game :D

Comment: Can I see an example usage of On Error Resume Next? Just in case, macros can be found here: http://pastebin.com/xhZthsJc